# Hide some payment options when paying for an order from the WooCommerce account page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway, hook-woocommerce

If the order has the Pending payment status, then the user can pay for it on the account page. This displays all available payment options. How to hide all payment methods except checks? I did it with CSS, but I would like to do it with a hook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
add_filter('woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'custom_available_payment_gateways');

function custom_available_payment_gateways($available_gateways) {

    $payment_ids = array('paypal'); // Here define the allowed payment methods ids to keep ( cod, stripe ... )
    
    // For Order pay
    if (is_wc_endpoint_url('order-pay')) {

        foreach ($available_gateways as $payment_id => $available_gateway) {
            if (!in_array($payment_id, $payment_ids)) {
                unset($available_gateways[$payment_id]);
            }
        }
    }

    return $available_gateways;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

disable the other payment methods from **woo-commerce<<settings<<payment**
[image: like this]

Comment: I need these payment methods on the checkout page. On the checkout page, depending on the selected shipping method, I display the desired payment method using the woocommerce_available_payment_gateways hook. But in the account page all payment methods are displayed.

Comment: use this short code in your account page where you wants to show the payment methods:  [woo_mypayment]

Comment: In your personal account, in the list of orders, an order with the Awaiting payment status has a "Pay" button. When you click on it, you get to a page like: /checkout/order-pay/ХХХХХ? pay_for_order=true&key=wc_order_fDs6dDAsfvfgr

This page already has all the included payment methods. I need to display only one of them.